# Combining Stack, Drawer and Tab Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble realising the following:

I want a Tab Navigation with two Tabs: `Home` and `Map`.
In the `Home` Tab I want a `Drawer Navigation`. Within the `Drawer Navigation` I want to be able to Navigate to the screens `Profile` and `About`. When clicking the `Back Button` from `Profile` or `About`, I want to come back to the open `Drawer Menu`.

Currently I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import DrawerContent from './DrawerContent';
import Mapp from './Mapp';
import Home from './Home';
import Profile from './Profile';
import About from './About';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
    return <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name='Tab'
            component={TabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen
            name='Profile'
            component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen
            name='About'
            component={About} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

const TabNavigator = () => {
    return <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name='Map' component={Mapp} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
}

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => DrawerContent(props)}>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeStackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}

const Navigation = () => {
    return <NavigationContainer>
        <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer >
}
```

and `<DrawerContent />` looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItemList,
    DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const DrawerContent = props => {
    return <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem label='Profile' onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Profile')} />
        <DrawerItem label='About' onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('About')} />

    </DrawerContentScrollView>
}

export default DrawerContent;
```

This gives me

The Tab Navigation (why is there a header with title `Tab`, I don't want this, but I must set `name prop` in `<HomeStackNavigator />`).

[image: Tab]

Then I can open the `Drawer` (works as expected)

[image: Drawer]

When I click on i.e. Profile I am only able to go back to `Tab`. Why not to `Drawer`?

[image: Clicked on Drawer Menu Item]

What also drives me nuts is, that I cannot remove the `Home` Menu Item in the `Drawer`.

Answer (score 1):

The drawer doesn't open in that scenario, you will need to open it yourself:

```
const HomeStackNavigator = () => {
    return <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name='Tab'
            component={TabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen
            name='Profile'
            component={Profile} 
            options={({ navigation }) => ({
               title: '',
              headerLeft: () => (
              <Button
                title="<"
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.goBack();
                  navigation.openDrawer();
              }}
            />
          ),
        })}/>
        <Stack.Screen
            name='About'
            component={About} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

Here's a [working Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/drawer-open-on-return).

[image: SS of line 52]

Comment: The Snack is not working... The screen becomes dark after loading it. I assume this is because the Drawer gets opened immedeatly after loading?

Comment: not sure why it's loading with a gray screen on top. If you make like a small change in the code (to trigger a hot reload), it will reload without the gray screen.

Comment: Now it works. But this is not what I tried to achieve. I do *not* want the Menu -Point Home in the `Drawer`. I further want, when I tap on `Profile` or `About` to be able to go Back to the open `Drawer menue`, *not*  back to `Tab`.

Comment: just making sure. so when you are already in the Profile screen, then click the back button, you want to drawer to open? and not go back to Tabs? if yes, you can just remove  line 52 in App.js `navigation.goBack();`

Comment: There is no such line.

Comment: It's there in App.js.

Comment: `line 52` in this snack https://snack.expo.io/@yoobit0616/drawer-open-on-return in `App.js` is `<Tab.Screen name="Home1" component={Home} />`
`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing a different line of code. I just added a SS of what i'm seeing. You can also do a search for the line if the line numbers are different. The code is `navigation.goBack();`